# Electrostatic stored energy of a continuous charge distribution

Tags: electrostatics, energy, work, potential-energy

If I have a charge distribution *A* at infinity and and another charge distribution at origin, say *B*, then the energy stored in the system when I bring the charge distribution *A* from infinity to a distance *r* near *B* is:

$W_{me} =( \epsilon_0/2)\int_{all\ of\  space} E^2 d\tau$.

My doubt is, is this electric field the electric field of *A* and *B* at *r* or is it just the electric field of *B* at *r*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field in that formula represent the field of both charges distributions. It contains the energy of bringing from infinity both charges distributions.

If you consider, for instance, only the field of $B$ (I don't know why you use vector notation if charge distributions are scalar) you won't get the energy that took to get $A$ whereever you want, simply because you aren't specifying anything about $A$ (like their position).

That equation is derived from
$$W = \frac{1}{2} \int_{V'} \phi\left(\mathbf{r'}\right) \rho\left(\mathbf{r'}\right) d^3\mathbf{r'} \text{.}$$
I would say that, in order to get the energy that it took bring the charge distribution $A$, you should do direct integraton of that integral where $\phi$ is the potential due to $B$ and $\rho$ is the distribution for $A$. Now that you are considering $B$ fixed (not counting it's energy), I'm doubting about that $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you for this! Also just to be sure, the energy we are talking about here is the stored energy right?

Comment: Yes. I don't see what other kind of energy would be implied other than potential energy.